# google maps v2 does not load after publishing in google play

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I recently developed an app based on google maps API v2, Before publishing i checked my app on my device and emulator it worked fine, but after publishing , (when downloading through google play) map does not load ,i see white space not map..

I am preety confused here.
Please guide me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: is this the normal behavior when publishing in google play for first time  ?

Answer (score 0):

it is not a normal behaviour at all.
"Maps API keys are linked to specific certificate/package pairs, rather than to users or applications. " 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

You need to get API key for your signing certificate and put in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add signature of your release key to the google api console.  **You can have more than one signature attached to each api key**.  This way the manifest will work in debug and release configurations with no changes.  This might be a duplicate question.